# calling class function in another class function in javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to call posts() in refresh function.
Here is my code.

```
var TIMELINE = TIMELINE || (function (){

    /*** private ***/
    var _args = {};
    var self = this;

    return {

        init : function(Args){
            _args = Args;
        },  // init
        posts : function(data) {

            alert('posts called');

        },  // posts
        unsetMarkers : function() {

            alert('unsetMarkers called');

        },   // unsetMarkers
        refresh :   function(){
            self.posts;
        }

    };


}());
```

the problem is at this line `self.posts;`
I also tried `self.posts({'data':'success','another':'thing'});`
How I can use posts in refresh?

Comment: *"I want to call posts() in refresh function."* Cool. And what's your question?

Comment: call like "self.posts(data);" :D
You also have to pass in Data. But I do not see data constructed anywhere.

Comment: @FlixKling 
the problem is at this line self.posts; I also tried self.posts(); How I can use posts in refresh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- `self` doesn't refer to the object with the property `posts`, i.e. not to the object you are returning from the function. You have `var self = this;` and `this` refers to `window` (assuming non-strict mode).
- You are not even trying to *call* the function.

Instead of returning the object immediately, assign it to `self`:

```
// instead of `var self = this;`
var self = {
   // function definitions
};

return self;
```

and then you can call the method with

```
self.posts(); // note the parenthesis after the function name
```

If you are certain that the `refresh` function is *always* called as `TIMELINE.refresh()` (i.e. as a method of the `TIMELINE` object) , then you can also call the `posts` method with

```
this.posts();
```

and forget about `self`.

---

Further reading material:

- [MDN - `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this): Learn which value `this` has in different contexts.
- [Eloquent JavaScript - Functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html): Learn how functions work.

Answer (score 0):

```
refresh :   function(){
    this.posts();
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NVkpX/)